# Android- Saving data in DynamoDB via app or lambda

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I' ve been developing Android app which is connected to AWS and I save data in DynamoDB in app using code:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = clientManager
                .ddb();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);

try {
     mapper.save(event);
}
```

I know that it is possible to manage data in DynamoDB via Lambda. My question is: Is it faster and safer to save and edit data in Lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would typically use API Gateway plus Lambda if you want to write to DynamoDB without your own back-end server. I'd expect it to be slower and more expensive to do that than if your client wrote directly to the DB, however.

If your client does go direct to the DB then [don't store access/secret keys in the app](http://www.cio.com/article/3158544/security/sensitive-access-tokens-and-keys-found-in-hundreds-of-android-apps.html). Use [Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html) or some other option to vend temporary keys.